# How to align sibling divs vertically to parent height dynamically

Tags: html, css

**I'm aware of the many solutions available to similar problems, and I tried them but nothing worked until now.**

---

I wanted to vertically align the elements in the following snippet to their parent height dynamically, but wasn't able to find a working method. Any suggestions?

```css
.wrap {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 1140px;
}

.container {
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 padding: 20px 5%;
}

.container p {
 margin: 0;
}

.left {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

.right {
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
 text-align: left;
 padding-left: 20px;
}

a.button {
 background-color: #333;
 border-bottom-width: 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 1;
 padding: 15px 20px;
}





/*
Baseline Normalize and Float Clearing
-------------------------------------------------- */

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block}audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden]{display:none}html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}a:link,
a:visited,a:hover,a:active,a:focus{outline:0 none;text-decoration:none}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}abbr[title]{border bottom:1px dotted}b,strong{font-weight:bold}dfn{font-style:italic}hr{-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;height:0}mark{background:#ff0;color:#000}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,serif;font-size:1em}pre{white-space:pre-wrap}q{quotes:"\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019"}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sup{top:-0.5em}sub{bottom:-0.25em}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:0}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}legend{border:0;padding:0}button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0}button,input{line-height:normal}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}

* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
 box-sizing:         border-box;
}

.wrap:before {
 content: " ";
 display: table;
}

.wrap:after {
 clear: both;
 content: " ";
 display: table;
}

/*
Baseline Normalize and Float Clearing
-------------------------------------------------- */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
      <p>This is an example of a sentence</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <a class="button" href="#">Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CSS table

You can use a combination of `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to achieve the vertically-cantered effect:

```
.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1140px;
  display: table;       /* Added */
}

.left {
  display: table-cell;  /* Added */
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.right {
  display: table-cell;  /* Added */
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1140px;
  display: table;
}

.container {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 20px 5%;
}

.container p {
  margin: 0;
}

.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

a.button {
  background-color: #333;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}


/*
Baseline Normalize and Float Clearing
-------------------------------------------------- */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block
}

audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0
}

[hidden] {
  display: none
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

body {
  margin: 0
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
  text-decoration: none
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: .67em 0
}

abbr[title] {
  border bottom: 1px dotted
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic
}

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em
}

pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap
}

q {
  quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019"
}

small {
  font-size: 80%
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em
}

img {
  border: 0
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden
}

figure {
  margin: 0
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: .35em .625em .75em
}

legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

button,
input {
  line-height: normal
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none
}

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer
}

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0
}

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.wrap:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}


/*
Baseline Normalize and Float Clearing
-------------------------------------------------- */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
      <p>This is an example of a sentence</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <a class="button" href="#">Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Flexbox

If you do not mind using [CSS flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (up to 97% browser support after adding vendor prefixes), simply removing the floats and using `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on the `.wrap` selector will work just as fine:

```
.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1140px;
  display: flex;        /* Added */
  align-items: center;  /* Added */
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1140px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 20px 5%;
}

.container p {
  margin: 0;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

a.button {
  background-color: #333;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}


/*
Baseline Normalize and Float Clearing
-------------------------------------------------- */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block
}

audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0
}

[hidden] {
  display: none
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

body {
  margin: 0
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
  text-decoration: none
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: .67em 0
}

abbr[title] {
  border bottom: 1px dotted
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic
}

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em
}

pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap
}

q {
  quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019"
}

small {
  font-size: 80%
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em
}

img {
  border: 0
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden
}

figure {
  margin: 0
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: .35em .625em .75em
}

legend {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

button,
input {
  line-height: normal
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none
}

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  cursor: pointer
}

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0
}

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.wrap:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}


/*
Baseline Normalize and Float Clearing
-------------------------------------------------- */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
      <p>This is an example of a sentence</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <a class="button" href="#">Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All right, It finally worked! Could you please tell me why you apply the `flex` to the `wrap` and not the `container`?

Comment: @Zelda That is because the vertical positioning of the elements is dependent on the `align-center` property, which affects only the direct descendents of the element. Therefore, you will have to use `display: flex` on the immediate parent of the siblings you want to vertically center, and in this case it will be `.wrap` and not the `.container` element.

Answer (score 0):

**Statically:**

Give .container a fixed height, and give it's child elements a height of 100%:

```
.container{
   height:140px;
}

.wrap, .left, .right{
   height:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b3y2pjtr/

**Dynamically:**

Ignore .container. Use flexbox properties on .wrap, .left, and .right:

```
.wrap{
   display:flex;
   width:100%;
}

.left, .right{
   flex:1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b3y2pjtr/1/